# How to get recent posts posted in a given geographic area within the last N hours/days

Tags: facebook

How would I got about getting posts, posted by anyone in a given geographic area within the last N hours/days.

Examples: 
1) Get all the posts (public assumed) posted by anyone in Palo Alto, CA within the last 4 hours.
2) Get all the posts (public assumed) posted by anyone near a given lat/lon within the last 4 hours.

1) assumes they have made their profile/address public
2) assumes they have their post geo-tagged

Is there any platform or graph API (or combination of) that would let me do this?

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same question, so I would be very happy if someone would answer this one. The closest I can find in the API document is this: To search for objects near a geographical location, use type=location and add the center and distance parameters: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000 That LOOKS like it should do what you want, but it is limited to your friends (by the auth key, apparently.) I am hoping for some way of using the API to get all of the posts in a given area (at least public ones) even if the user ID and even the content we